# How can I emulate an XXHDPI device in Eclipse

Tags: android

I would like to emulate an XXHDPI device in Eclipse. I've updated everything via the SDK manager but there doesn't seem to be the tools available to do this.

Has anyone managed this, or do I need to wait for a further release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Window --> Android Virtual Device Manager --> Device Definitions --> New...

There you can create a new standard device, which you could per example call Nexus 10.

The size would be xlarge and density xxhdpi.

The screen size (in) 10 inch, and the resolution 2560x1600

Just play around with the rest for a bit, but they shouldn't matter to much for simply emulating the screen itself.

[image]

*forgot to put Camera's correctly, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried this, but I get an error when attempting to start the device: emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!! This only happens when I specify xxhdpi, for my xhpdi emulators it's fine.

Comment: Reducing the API level from 17 to 16 solved the problem above. The Emulator starts up, although so far I just get a black screen.

Comment: Starting this thing up in the emulator will take LONG :)

Comment: Well your answer is correct, and helpful, though I've not managed to get the thing to start up yet. After ages (a long, long time...), it's just a black screen still and the logcat is spitting out endless garbage!

Comment: Yeah, its a known issue with the emulator shamefully. You could try to put in less RAM. 2gb is the realistic RAM with the nexus10, but if you're only interested in testing the screen you won't need it and it will boot faster with less RAM setted.

Comment: I, too, am trying to get an xxhdpi device displaying and cannot. I want to emulate the Galaxy S4, and have tried on a MAC and Ubuntu machine, both entering the values manually and using the Sony-provided device profile for their xxhdpi phone. All I see is a blank screen.

Comment: [Post about XXHDPI may help you](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-develop-android-application-for.html)